# What does "True dat" mean?

Tags: slang

I recently read a blog and come across the phrase "True dat".
I think it means "Agree". But what is "dat" exactly?
Thanks,

Comment: Dat is "that." The phrase equates to "that is true."

Comment: Affirmative. Agreed. see The Urban Dictionary [**Tru Dat**](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=tru+dat)

Answer (score 7):

"True dat" is African American Vernacular English for "That's true".

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zX9RVI0vaDs

Comment: Hi Tim, [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) guidelines recommend that we refrain from answering a low-quality question so as to discourage users from asking them. This question was gen-ref and didn't show research. Your intentions were good, but please keep this in mind. Hope you understand

Comment: @Area 51 Detective Fiction: I don't disagree with the principle, but do disagree that this question is general reference.  The word "dat" doesn't appear in Cambridge, Collins, or Merriam-Webster, for example, and the phrase could also be syntactically puzzling, since it apparently lacks a verb and begins with an adjective.

Comment: In that case, you should check if a comment would suffice, rather than an answer post. Just saying.

Comment: I'm quite glad that other areas of SE do not follow that rule, but instead either wkrk to improve yhe question or downvote it or flag/close-vote, as appropriate. Your room, your game, your rules, but...

Comment: @keshlam: I'm not against your suggestions. They go without saying. The OP could be instructed to edit their post to conform to site rules in the comments. Nobody's rallying against downvoting/flagging. But if people keep answering, it lends weight to the question and makes it look legit.

Comment: A belated comment:  One of the so-called "general references" on the internet refers to this phrase as a "bastardized version" of **that's true**. Remember that next time you're ready to click the Close button.

Answer (score 2):

It means "that is true."  "Dat" is used for "that" in some dialects.

Comment: Hi Bob, you seem new here, but [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) guidelines recommend that we refrain from answering a low-quality question so as to discourage users from asking them. This question was gen-ref and didn't show research. Your intentions were good, but please keep this in mind. Hope you understand